# Cost-Effective yet reliable earth detection circuit with <100µA current draw

Tags: ac, grounding, leakage-current

I'm working on a cost-effective circuit to detect the presence of an earth ground connection in a 230V AC mains line (at 50Hz). One of the key design constraints is to keep the current draw less than 100µA.

I first tried using a high-value resistor (like 2.2MΩ) from live to earth, and measure the voltage drop across this resistor, but this didn't meet my requirements.

I've also considered using an optocoupler, like the PC817 or the H11AA1. The issue I see with this is that their operational forward current is typically around 5-20mA and 10mA respectively, which exceeds my current limit.

I've explored powering a circuit using an LM358 and a capacitive dropper, but this introduced a leakage current of about 50mA to the earthing system which is unacceptable.

Given these constraints and issues, what cost-effective alternatives or modifications would you recommend to detect an earth connection reliably while limiting the current to <100µA?

Comment: Are you sticking something into the actual ground (like a copper rod) and then seeing if either of the two mains leads has a low impedance to it? Or something else?

Comment: What are your requirements? what power supply? what circuit connections are made?

Comment: Indeed, the intended configuration is to connect the circuit to live and earth. My preliminary design involved a voltage divider setup with live, neutral, and earth, with an LM358 to monitor the voltage changes. However, finding a cost-effective solution has posed some challenges. For instance, when I tried to use a capacitive dropper to power the LM358, the GFCI would trip as soon as I connected the output from the 2.2MOhm resistor. I discovered this was due to a 50mA current leakage.

Comment: @15Volts Are you expecting this to be line-powered? No battery? Or will it have its own DC supply?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make it line powered. Actually, I made a EMI filter that has components like varistor, TVS diode, and class Y2 capacitors connected to live and earth. I've tested, the capacitor is leaking 0.3mA. The TVS and Varistor will redirect huge current to earthing in case the voltage difference between live and earth is significant. But in case of earth fault, these components will leak 0.3mA or more to the earth pin. If you connect a metal body with earthing, touching it will shock you. My circuit aims to mitigate this by disconnecting these components in case of an earth fault.

Comment: I aim to limit the current draw to under 100µA, as even this can cause a tingling sensation. Anything higher could be hazardous, particularly in scenarios where earth is absent. If a metal object with an earth connection, like a fridge or microwave, is linked, my circuit could potentially create a fault. This is due to the capacitors, varistors, and TVS diodes bridging live and the object's body, a situation that I must prevent to ensure safety. Some designs use LED indicators for fault detection, but these can deliver substantial shocks in the absence of an earth connection.

Comment: It only connects to line neutral and earth? what is the output?  please describe the problem you are trying to solve in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version of the Earth fault detection circuit that operates at an average current of 48-50µA. Here's the schematics I drew in EasyEDA:

[image: EasyEDA Schematics]

Here's the circuit in real life ):

[image: Circuit Prototype]

#### Working:

- Input: A full-wave bridge rectifier is connected to a pair of 2.2MΩ resistors, which are responsible for the low current draw.
- Voltage Stabilization: The output from the rectifier charges a capacitor through a diode. This capacitor serves to smooth out the rectified waveform.
- Triggering: The voltage across the capacitor controls a DB3 diac, which starts conducting when the voltage across it reaches a certain level (the breakover voltage), and continues to conduct until the voltage falls below a certain threshold (the holding voltage).
- Inductor Charging: When the diac conducts, it discharges the capacitor, allowing the stored energy to charge an inductor.
- Optocoupler Activation: The energy in the inductor powers up an optocoupler, which emits a brief flash of light, lasting about 100µs.
- Detection: On the isolated side of the circuit, a 74123N Retriggerable Monostable Multivibrator IC detects these brief pulses. This IC can then be used to trigger an LED or a relay, signalling the presence of an Earth fault.

This design allows for a cost-effective, low-power solution to the problem of Earth fault detection. The circuit can run indefinitely with minimal current draw and provides a clear visual or relay-driven indication of fault conditions.

#### Test:

Do note, the AC high voltage part of the circuit begins operation from 65VAC and can handle considerably high voltages. My tests involved the use of a 100K resistor with the circuit at 460VAC, and it consumed about 5mA of current - all while maintaining normal operation.

Tests with the 4.4 megaohm configuration at 460VAC yielded satisfactory results, although at this voltage the circuit consumes about twice the current. This level won't cause a shock but may produce a noticeable tingle. Bear in mind, direct contact with this voltage is extremely dangerous (Tread carefully - it's a "one mistake game").

Here's an image the LED is blinking at close to 480VAC.

[image: LED at 477VAC blinking - off]

[image: LED at 479VAC blinking - on]

For use as a light, this design can accommodate several hundreds of volts to kilovolts without failure, provided the resistors and full-bridge rectifier are rated for such voltages.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps NE2 neon indicator with 220K in series? this is the old "neon screwdriver" circuit.

Comment: Yes, I have done that with some success. I used a "Vactrol" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistive_opto-isolator This was for a ground integrity sensor on a high current breaker test set that could be connected to 208, 220, 240, 277, or 480 VAC. So I used two 100k resistors across the supply connectors, and the center tap through the Vactrol to the frame. But it could be "fooled" due to capacitance and normal leakage.

Comment: Yes, that's actually a very nice idea I tried to look into. I have seen that those neon bulbs need just 0.1mA - that's what I want exactly. Using that with an LDR for example, will isolate the signal, but I don't think it's reliable for production use because the neon lamps have lots of reliability issues - they get black, sometimes they flicker, and all that sort of stuff...

Answer (score 2):

This circuit provides an isolated high impedance input.

If T1 is not conducting, the D input voltage of the flipflop follows the rising edge of the pulse and drops down with rising inductor current. The voltage is sampled a very short time after the rising edge, defined by R04 and C2. In this case the flipflop reads and stores a high signal.

If MOSFET T1 is conducting, the inductance on the secondary side is much lower and the D input sees a logic 0 at the rising edge of each clock pulse. The output stays low.

D2 and R05 protect the input stage of the flipflop from voltages below GND.

If more inputs are required a 4 or 8 bit D register can be used. I use this circuit with an 1 mH transformer, but the idea might work with other, lower values.

The flipflop can be replaced by software if a strict timing between output of the generated positive edge and reading of the (D) input is used.

[image: High-Z HVAC input]